# Can I use IL2CPP (Intermediate Language To C++) for non-Unity applications?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

[IL2CPP.exe](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP.html) is a Unity utility for converting C# IL code to C++.  My question is: can this executable be used *outside* of the Unity game-development environment as a general-purpose tool for converting *any* .NET application (not just games) to a high-performance native executable?

Although I do know *some* C++, It would certainly be nice to be able write *all* kinds of programs in a language I am comfortable and fluent with (C#)......whether they be audio/video/music-production DAWs or OS-level security/forensics tools or machine-learning platforms or anything else that's resource-intensive.......and know that they will run as efficiently as an app written in straight C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update 2023:

Based on @StackHola update, it is possible to generate C++ code from C# using [IL2CPP Command Line](https://il2cppdumper.com/reverse/using-il2cpp-to-generate-command-line), but you would probably not get any performance benefits doing so, see my Long answer from 2021.

## Short answer: NO

IL2CPP is tightly connected to the Unity environment and it's not possible to use it outside of Unity. You would need to write your own converter(?) to do such a thing.

## Longer answer

IL2CPP doesn't do any magic in terms of performance improvement. Comparing C++ with C# with IL2CPP code should give (almost - more below) no performance benefit.

IL2CPP is performant compared to C# code written for Unity specifically for few reasons that have nothing to do with C++.

**Why Unity is unique and needs IL2CPP:**

- Unity API is very heavily reliant on main thread performance, as the whole Unity API was written almost 10 years ago, where 2 Core CPUs were top-notch and everyone believed that we will have 20-50GHz single-core CPUs by now.
- Unity makes a lot of assumptions that you will use their API for everything, begging from IO to Threading and GPU access, which is heavily bound to C++ core.
- Unity needs to be wrapped with Unity objects (MonoBehaviours and GameObjects) to be used for almost anything, you cannot write your own native anything. (This is a simplification)
- Unity is written in C++, so it needs to do something very similar to Marshalling, and it's not very efficient.

**So why IL2CPP?**

- Unity cannot convert its already very legacy backend (Mono) and its legacy API to be multithreaded since Mono have a lot of assumptions about your code that are not easily convertible to "simple" unity API.
- Unity core is written in C++, so they are eliminating any form of Marshalling all together by skipping Mono "translator".
- IL2CPP converts highly inefficient C#, single-threaded code to multithreaded C++, where possible, and it does this by analyzing IL code.

**Is it worth converting other C# to C++?**

**No!** Compare any arbitrary, optimized C# code that was precompiled by AOT to (modern) C++. You should get the same performance! Identical I would say.

C# is compiled to IL (Intermediate Language) which as the name suggests is Intermediate. It's converted in runtime to Native Binary code (only when needed), that is what C++ is compiled into. You can force this conversion by skipping IL generation by running Ahead of Time compilation (AOT).

The ONLY thing that your C# code will be less performant is when you are abusing GC's ability to clean up after you.

Comment: "*modern C++ have GC as well*" Not in the language itself. There exist libraries like Boehm GC but those are not part of the standard.

Comment: @dxiv I cannot find relevant information, but I thought they added GC to C++11 via `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is a [`RAII`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) wrapper, nothing GC about it.

Comment: Fair enough description of it, I guess. Have you looked at DOTS btw? Is kinda a refactor of the core for parallelizing and otherwise optimising things, with data in arrays instead of objects kind of.

Comment: @antont DOTS is built on top of the IL2CPP core. They are using an existing stack that they use for "normal" unity code and sprinkle some more under the hood magic to it. You can do the same thing in C# if you wish to write your own engine. Just keep all the data in multiple arrays, grouped by object type and process every group in parallel and you have DOTS in C#! Just remember to not allocate memory all the time so that GC do not have to work for you :)

Comment: I would say that besides abusing the GC, a naive programmer can make C# slower by, for example, using managed code to iterate large arrays rather than using unsafe pointers, etc. And on the extremely rare occasion that you do find something that just can't be optimized, you can always put it in a C++ DLL and call it from your C# code.

Comment: @Digiproc If you need to micro-optimize CLR than you can do more bad then good when iterating using pointers instead of managed looping. If you are memory conscious and do a `for` instead of `foreach` then you should be fine when it comes down to performance and be on pair with C++ looping performance wise. Even in managed C# environment.

Comment: "and everyone believed that we will have 20-50GHz single-core CPUs by now." In 2011, most people in tech already know this was never going to be a thing. Intel already tried (and failed) with his NetBurst architecture about 20 years ago.

Comment: @tigrou It looks like not everyone got the memo ;)

Comment: Some statements would need more information in order to be considered : "IL2CPP is tightly connected to the Unity environment and it's not possible to use it outside of Unity" and "Is it worth converting other C# to C++? No!". For instance you might want to use native libraries in some context/platforms.

Comment: @StackHola you can use native platform code from C# directly with `extern` you do not need IL2CPP to use C++ libraries. It could be beneficial to have a native binary for a given platform, but you can achieve the same result with AOT (Ahead of time compilation) without proprietary IL2CPP wrapper around .NET

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that it can be used as an independant tool through the CLI :

> IL2CPP does not actually require Unity at all. It can work as a completely standalone tool, which also means it can produce things like executable binaries for regular .NET console applications that don’t have any connection with Unity.

https://il2cppdumper.com/reverse/using-il2cpp-to-generate-command-line

Comment: Even if it's possible my points still stand, and it's not a magical wand that will erase all your programming mistakes.